# Is it possible to track if QLineEdit was clicked on?

Tags: c++, qt

### What does the documentation say

---

`QPushButton` has a [`clicked()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal so one can do something like this

```
connect(ui->Btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(DoSmth()));
```

`QLineEdit` has a [`textEdited()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited) signal that allows to track the edit action.

### What I am trying to achieve

---

I'm trying to run a function when a `QLineEdit` was just clicked on, not edited. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe subclass QLineEdit and reimplement QWidget::focusInEvent

Comment: Have you found my answer usefull?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass QLineEdit and reimplement QWidget::focusInEvent, where you can check if the reason of the focus was mouse click. Then use this subclass instead of QLineEdit. You may create a custom signal and emit it from this event handler too to be able to use it through signal/slots.

```
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QFocusEvent>

class FocusHandlerLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent * event) {
        QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
        if(event->reason() == Qt::MouseFocusReason)
            emit gotFocus();
    }

signals:
    void gotFocus();
};
```